# C# Select Query Failed with no errors

Tags: c#, select

I'm having trouble with a simple SELECT query, I cannot see why it isn't working.

Here is the code:

```
conn.Open();

string GetPayrollQuery = "SELECT PayrollNo FROM [Employee] WHERE (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) = @Name";    
OleDbCommand GetPayroll = new OleDbCommand(GetPayrollQuery, conn);

GetPayroll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cbbEmployees.Text;

var GotPayroll = GetPayroll.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show(GotPayroll.ToString());

return Convert.ToInt32(GotPayroll);
```

The code runs fine however it isn't extracting the data. Can anyone see why this would be?

Comment: Could you clean this up a little bit?

Comment: try `GetPayroll.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: Well, you're setting up a query, then calling `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: `GetPayroll.ExecuteScalar()` returns the same as ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: Can you try changing the way you're setting up your parameter? Try: `GetPayroll.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", cbbEmployees.Text));` Have a look at [this article](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). You will also need to change `ExecuteNonQuery` to `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: @DrewKennedy That hasn't changed anything either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cbbEmployees.SelectedText`. Fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I bet @name is coming as "MikeSmith" instead of "Mike Smith".

Comment: I've checked that using a messagebox.show command and that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the same query runs in SQL using those parameter values.
2. Change `GetPayroll.ExecuteNonQuery()` to `GetPayroll.ExecuteScalar()` so to return a single result.
3. Change `GetPayroll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cbbEmployees.Text;` to `GetPayroll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", cbbEmployees.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

3 things:

- try to open SQL profiler and check what you are executing on database
- check database collation, is it case sensitive?
- remove executenonquery (it's must used with update, delete, not select) and try executescalar (if one result for one row is exptected, otherwise try to fill a datatable or use datareader)